# Is there a better way to loop through only visible cells of a column and compare the current cell to the next cell and the cell two after?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code to try and count when the performance value goes up a certain degree from one cell to the next, but sometimes I need to count if the performance has gone up two cells in advance, and only count those situations once. The code I have been using throws an error at random intervals, and I cannot determine why. I am very new at VBA.

I have tried several different methods of only looking through the filtered cells only, to no avail when it comes to comparing cells.

```
Dim i As Variant
i = 1

On Error GoTo ErrLoops:

ErrCountLoop:

Do While i < 328

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True And ((ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i + 1).Value) <> "") And ((ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i).Value) < -45) And (((ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i + 1).Value) - 25) > (ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i).Value)) And ((ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i + 2).Value) - 50 > (ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i).Value)) And ((ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells _
            (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(i + 1).Value) > -85) Then

            count3 = count3 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then


    End If
    i = i + 1

  Loop
If i > 328 Then
    GoTo StackCount
End If

ErrLoops:
i = i + 1
Resume ErrCountLoop

StackCount:
MsgBox "Number of stacks = " & count3
```

Comment: What is the error, and on what line does it occur?

Comment: Warcupine It errors as type mismatch on the if statement of the loop sometimes, such as at the 70th and 71st iteration of the loop, and later on as well, up towards 200. It used to error the first time at the 54th iteration, but then switched to the 71st, regardless of what data set I run.

Comment: does the data contain worksheet error values (e.g. `#N/A`, `#VALUE`, `#REF!`, etc.)?

Comment: No it doesn't, strictly values, no formulas at all

Comment: Are they all numbers?

Comment: You have a lot of clauses in that `And`'ed `If` test - remember VBA doesn't short-circuit tests, so all comparisons will be evaluated, even if an earlier one fails.  Also, if any of the Areas have >1 cell you can't do something like compare `.Value` directly with a number or "".  You might consider breaking out your tests and making sure all areas are single-cell ranges.  Also pusing a range variable in place of `ActiveSheet.Range(rng3.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will make your code 10x more readable.

Comment: Warcupine, yes, and Tim thanks i will try all of these. Like I said, I'm still getting the hang of this sort of thing